# Is there a way to create an annotation that behaves like an interface?

Tags: java, java-8, annotations

Problem Statement: I would like to create an annotation that behaves like an interface. The expectation is that any class that used this annotation should override the methods defined.
I would also like that a dynamic way to create instances based a name, ie: the annotated classes.

Something like

```
public @interface Food
{
    public boolean isOrganic(String content);
}


@Food
class Potato {
    public boolean isOrganic(String content)
    {
       ....
       return true;
    }
}

@Food
class Tomato {
    public boolean isOrganic(String content)
    {
       ....
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just an interface, isn't it?

Comment: It is not possible at current state of technology/java (please use "normal interface" - problem solved)

Comment: This is possible.  You will need to write an annotation processor and run it on every compilation.  The annotation processor will issue an error if a class annotated with the annotation does not define a given method.  But, using a regular Java interface seems like a better solution.

Comment: @tackline The given code defines an annotation, not an interface.  Note the `@` in `@interface Food`.  (The Java syntax for defining an annotation is funny, and is easy to mistake for a regular Java interface.)

Comment: @mernst Yeah, remove the `@`, and classes you have annotated `@Food` make `implements Food`. Job done.